# How to get telegram user location

Tags: python, telegram

I am making a telegram bot api wrapper and was wondering how to get the user's location. I have tried this:

```
def test(chat):
    reply_markup = {
        "chat_id" : chat,
        "text": "your message",
        "reply_markup":
        {"keyboard":
         [
             [{"text": "Send Your Mobile", "request_contact": True}],
             [{"text": "Send Your Location", "request_location": True}]
         ]
        }
        }
```

and:

```
def func():
    keyboard = [{"text":"Hello", "request_location":True}]
    reply_markup = {"keyboard":keyboard, "one_time_keyboard":True}
    return json.dumps(reply_markup)
```

to make a thing to submit to my send_messages func which I got from: https://www.codementor.io/garethdwyer/building-a-telegram-bot-using-python-part-1-goi5fncay

How would I do that?

Answer (score 2):

First, you can only use `request_location` in private chat, make sure it is not send to group.

If succeeded, user will send location as message, just like sendLocation method, you need to handle new message to get location.

Answer (score 1):

- [For pyTelegramBotAPI users](https://groosha.gitbooks.io/telegram-bot-lessons/content/chapter9.html#comment-3742511214)
- For python-telegram-bot users:

  ```
  dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.location, location))

  def location(bot, update):
      print(update.message.location)
  ```

Comment: this works fine ,can we fetch location on any message from user ?

Comment: @Nilanj no, that's not allowed due privacy concerns. You need to explicitly ask the geolocation to the user so they can authorize or not.